# Not writing a value in XML with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have the following query which is part of a bigger XML. The issue is that is not writing the 0 value of the ELSE and writes an empty element `<SellingLocation>` in the XML. I can't find why. This is the query code.

```
SELECT (
    SELECT TOP 1
        CASE WHEN COUNT(ac.SKU) > 0
            THEN l.ZoneId + ' ' + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(10), l.Bays), 0, 4)
            ELSE 0
        END
    FROM #ARTSCreditTrans ac
    INNER JOIN LocationSKU l ON ac.SKU = l.SKU
    WHERE ac.PickTake = 'P'
    GROUP BY ZoneId, Bays
)
FOR XML PATH('SellingLocation'), TYPE
```

@Devart, how can I make the same modification in the case of a query which has more that one option and the filter with the having doesn't look like the solution? For example:

```
SELECT [text()] = ISNULL((
    SELECT TOP 1 
    CASE WHEN COUNT(oh.OrderNumber) > 0 
         THEN oh.Latitude
         ELSE CASE WHEN td.RegisterID = 80
                   THEN SUBSTRING(tt.ShipMidInit, 1, CHARINDEX('|', tt.ShipMidInit) - 1)
                   END
         END
    FROM OrderHeader oh INNER JOIN TranDetail td ON oh.OrderNumber = td.DocNumber JOIN TranTotal tt ON td.DocNumber = tt.DocNumber
    WHERE td.PickTake = 'P'
    GROUP BY oh.Latitude, td.RegisterID, tt.ShipMidInit
), '')
FOR XML PATH('Latitude'), TYPE
```

Comment: are you sure `COUNT(ac.SKU) > 0` isn't always true?  and do you just get blank or one space?

Comment: `COUNT(ac.SKU) > 0` *MUST* always be true, since any null values of `ac.SKU` are removed because of the `INNER JOIN` on this column. Therefore you will never reach the `ELSE` condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT [text()] = ISNULL((
    SELECT TOP 1 CAST(l.ZoneId AS VARCHAR(100)) + ' ' + CAST(l.Bays AS VARCHAR(5))
    FROM #ARTSCreditTrans ac
    JOIN dbo.LocationSKU l ON ac.SKU = l.SKU
    WHERE ac.PickTake = 'P'
    GROUP BY ZoneId, Bays
    HAVING COUNT(ac.SKU) > 0
), '0')
FOR XML PATH('SellingLocation'), TYPE
```

Comment: Great modification to the query Devant. Really helped!

Comment: Devart please take a look to the editing that i included in the question.

Comment: please provide a small info about business logic of your query. it's a bit unclear for me - what's need to do...

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping the `0` in quotes (`'`):

```
SELECT (
                    SELECT TOP 1
                        CASE WHEN COUNT(ac.SKU) > 0
                            THEN l.ZoneId + ' ' + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(10), l.Bays), 0, 4)
                            ELSE '0'
                            END
                    FROM #ARTSCreditTrans ac INNER JOIN LocationSKU l ON ac.SKU = l.SKU
                    WHERE ac.PickTake = 'P'
                    GROUP BY ZoneId, Bays
                    )
                FOR XML PATH('SellingLocation')
                , TYPE
```